# Console.log in Chrome dev tools console doesn't do anything

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

So I open the Chrome developer tools and switch to the console tab, and I type the command `console.log("Hello world!")` but it doesn't log anything to the console. Why doesn't it work? Thanks.

Here is a screenshot of it
[image: screenshot]

Comment: Do you have a screenshot?

Comment: I've just added a screenshot now

Comment: [`console.log`](https://i.imgur.com/V79h0tE.png) can be overwritten. Just enter `console.log` into the console to check if that's the case.

Comment: @ASOwnerYT What is the URL of the page? I guess they overwrite `console.log` with a function that either does nothing or maybe sends the log to their server.

Answer (score -1):

Seems to be working as expected on Chrome 100.0.4896.75
[image]

Answer (score -1):

I had same problem, just reinstall Chrome and restart your computer.

[image]

Update: I don't know why but on my development environment just works with:
`console.debug()` and
`console.error()`